# How to plot XY points?

Tags: r, r-sp, r-sf

How do I plot points like those in dt?

```
dt <- list(structure(c(30.417963152251, -91.1871239471436), 
                   class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
                   structure(c(30.4171489671194, -91.1836263465881), 
                   class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
                   structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_), 
                   class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")))
```

This seems to work but I wondered what is the correct way to pass a list of `POINT`:

```
plot(c(dt[[1]], dt[[2]]))
```

[image]

I would prefer a solution in `sf` because then I need to calculate distances between points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sf` package:

```
dt <- lapply(dt, sf::st_point)

dt <- sf::st_as_sfc(dt)

plot(sf::st_geometry(dt))
```

Comment: This seems sufficient `dt <- sf::st_as_sfc(dt); plot(dt)`